# Import Excel 2016 data to local DB using ASP.net & C# in VS 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to import the data from Excel 2016 to a localDB created in VS2015 using ASP.net & C#.

Below is my code but when I run it, it gives me this error:

> "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred.
>   Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event
>   log for error details."

I'm able to connect to my localDB using Server Explorer.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

```
if (File.Exists(savePath))
    {
        //string strConnection = "Data Source=MySystem;Initial Catalog=MySamplesDB;Integrated Security=True";
        string strConnection = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\inetpub\wwwroot\WebSite\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Context Connection=False";
        string excelConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + savePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;Persist Security Info=False;";
        OleDbConnection excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(excelConnectionString);
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("Select * from [Sheet1$]", excelConnection);
        excelConnection.Open();
        OleDbDataReader dReader;
        dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        SqlBulkCopy sqlBulk = new SqlBulkCopy(strConnection);
        sqlBulk.DestinationTableName = "Robot";
        sqlBulk.WriteToServer(dReader);
        excelConnection.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error for sure is from the Connection String of SQL.

```
use (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB instead of (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
```

Notice the two back slashes required because \v and \t means special characters.

Also no need to use full DB Path when your mdf file is in AppData folder just use the fileName.mdf instead.

if you are unsure about your instance MSSQLLocalDB then

```
use Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;Database=filename.mdf;
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my connection string to "@"Server=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Database=Database.mdf;" & I'm not getting the same error. However, it is now giving me "Could not find installable ISAM" error. I've tried using single quotes & double quotes after Extended Properties but it's not helping.

Comment: There's no 64 bit version of the Jet OLEDB drivers, if you are running this code on 64 bit OS the change the target to 'x86' NOT 'Any CPU'